# Web scraping with BeautifulSoup Python returns None

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to get some text from `http://rss.cnn.com/rss/money_markets.rss` and when I run the code i keep getting the a `None` output. If it helps, I trying to get all the small headlines from the web and also the text under them in clear. Thank you!

```
import requests
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
web = requests.get("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/money_markets.rss")
start = bs4.BeautifulSoup(web.text, 'lxml')
scrape = start.find(".regularitem")
for i in scrape:
    print(scrape)
```

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Browser renders the data at `http://rss.cnn.com/rss/money_markets.rss` in an user friendly way, i.e. as HTML, but the data itself is actually XML. You can check that out by `print(response.headers['content-type'])` which returns `'text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1'`. Hence, what you are after is `item` XML elements. Also, I would suggest using `find_all()` to get all the elements instead of `find()` which returns just the first one.

```
import bs4
import requests

response = requests.get("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/money_markets.rss")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
for item in soup.find_all("item"):
    print(item.title.text)
    print(item.description.text)
    print("\n")
```